# iPhone UIImage Display Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to be able to display a UIImage from within my app and support a lot of the functionality available in the built-in Photos app (i.e., pinch-to-zoom, pan, etc).  I don't really want to write a bunch of code that someone has already written, so I'm wondering if there is a library out there already that I could just import into my project.

I'm aware of the Three20 project, but I don't want to import a huge library if I don't have to.

Is anyone aware of an available library that's already out there for displaying UIImages?  Or part of some open-source project that can be pulled out on its own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIScrollView.

There is a great video from [WWDC](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) (must be enrolled in the iOS developer program) on how to do this. Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views.

The sample code for this session is the PhotoScroller app you can download from the SDK site.